# Settings in PyCharm does not offer me an interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, settings

I recently got this problem: There is a project, I worked in it, but after some manipulations with the git, I have such a situation - nothing is offered to me in the settings. I attach screenshots

[image]

Comment: I assume you worked in one computer on the project and then switched to another. Did you install all the requirements  to run the project ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What PyCharm version are you using? (I'm also not a Mac user.) Normally the `Python Interpreter` is a sub-item inside `Build, Execution, Deploy` and is configured per project. I think I haven't seen the layout you are showing since PyCharm 2019. This also seems similar to [the issue in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68203363) see if that perhaps solves the problem.

Comment: Close PyCharm, remove the hidden folder `.idea` in the project root, reopen the project. The strange project-tree-highlighting suggests the project settings got corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Pavel Karateev is correct. Remove *.idea/*, close PyCharm, and reopen the project.

Someone committed .idea/ to the git repository by mistake. This is likely what corrupted the PyCharm project settings. You can see that the text is in white, whereas *venv/* and *.env* are in yellow (excluded from the repository by *.gitignore*).

To fix it permanently, do `git rm -r .idea/` and add .idea/ to the *.gitignore*.